# js - get json with variable

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic object property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name)

```
                  $.ajax({
                      url: "ranktonumber.json",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (data) {
                       // my problem is what should be in this line
                      }
                  });
```

Like you saw , i have jquery (ajax) command that give me json variable .
Let's said that I have another variable called "rank" .
"rank" is the key of the json .
The json is :

```
{"Recruit":"1",
"Private":"2",
"Private*":"3",
"Private**":"4",
"Private***":"5",
"Corporal":"6",
"Corporal*":"7",
"Corporal**":"8",
"Corporal***":"9"}
```

how can i use "rank" in json , because that won't work :

```
data.rank
```

If you didn't understand yet , here is how i can do it in mirc :

```
$json(jsonvariable,rankvariable)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic object property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamic-object-property-name) and also related to [How to use a variable as a json atribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540165/how-to-use-a-variable-as-a-json-atribute).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `data[rank]` instead of `data.rank`

Comment: Please vote to close the question as well, it's a duplicate. @user1515823: What is the value of `ranke`? Do `console.log(data)` and `console.log(rank)` and have a look wether the key really exists. This might help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-access-a-specific-value

Comment: Iv'e made new file with [this source](http://pastebin.com/LszuHAQg) and it alert underfinded

Comment: @user1515823: You named the variable holding the object `jsonobject`, not `JSON`. `JSON` is a pre-existing global variable and does not have a property `Private`. Try `jsonobject[rank]`.

Comment: i'm so stupid :) , let me check the page that i ask about him

Comment: i have problem in [my page](http://pastebin.com/gjVGFJcr)
here is the [console](http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/3011/c8a4eaaadd3b494fb63a179.png)

Comment: @user1515823: The file `ranktonumber.json` cannot be found by the server. Make sure the path is correct. This has nothing to do with your question though.

Comment: i've made function to do it: [click me](http://pastebin.com/i0B7vtt5)
but when I 
     document.write(ranktonum("God of War")); 
it returns me underfinded

Comment: slove it
thanks to @xdazz and Felix Kling

Answer (score 0):

```
var thisObj=this;

$.ajax({ 
url: "ranktonumber.json", 
dataType: "json", 
success: function (data) {  
thisObj.data=data;
});

console.log (thisObj.data["rank"])
```